# What is the progress object to upload functions on Minio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, minio

I know that this can be a dumb question but, what's the Progress object that I must pass to MinIO to see the upload status of an object?

- This documentation:
  https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-api-reference.html
- The method:

  `fput_object(bucket_name, object_name, file_path, content_type="application/octet-stream", metadata=None, sse=None, progress=None, part_size=0, num_parallel_uploads=3, tags=None, retention=None, legal_hold=False)`
- An example provided by the documentation:

  ```
  # Upload data with progress bar.
  result = client.fput_object(
      "my-bucket", "my-object", "my-filename",
      progress=Progress(),
  )
  print(
      "created {0} object; etag: {1}, version-id: {2}".format(
          result.object_name, result.etag, result.version_id,
      ),
  )
  ```

The problem is the object `Progress`, I cannot find an applicable instance to run it. Can anyone help me on this or provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the source code in the link.

https://github.com/minio/minio-py/blob/master/examples/progress.py

```
from minio import Minio
from minio.error import S3Error
import sys
import time
import urllib3
from queue import Empty, Queue
from threading import Thread

_BAR_SIZE = 20
_KILOBYTE = 1024
_FINISHED_BAR = '#'
_REMAINING_BAR = '-'

_UNKNOWN_SIZE = '?'
_STR_MEGABYTE = ' MB'

_HOURS_OF_ELAPSED = '%d:%02d:%02d'
_MINUTES_OF_ELAPSED = '%02d:%02d'

_RATE_FORMAT = '%5.2f'
_PERCENTAGE_FORMAT = '%3d%%'
_HUMANINZED_FORMAT = '%0.2f'

_DISPLAY_FORMAT = '|%s| %s/%s %s [elapsed: %s left: %s, %s MB/sec]'

_REFRESH_CHAR = '\r'



def main():
    # Create client with anonymous access.

    client = Minio(
        "192.168.2.193:9000",
        access_key="access",
        secret_key="password",
        secure=False,
        http_client=urllib3.ProxyManager(
            "http://192.168.2.193:9000",
            timeout=urllib3.Timeout.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
            # cert_reqs="CERT_REQUIRED",
            retries=urllib3.Retry(
                total=5,
                backoff_factor=0.2,
                status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504],
            ),
        ),
    )


    found = client.bucket_exists('test1')
    if not found:
        client.make_bucket('test1')
    else:
        print('Bucket test1 already exists')

    client.fput_object('test1', 'dgk_csv_no_space.zip', 'D:/dgk_csv_no_space.zip', progress=Progress())

    print("success")

class Progress(Thread):
    """
        Constructs a :class:`Progress` object.
        :param interval: Sets the time interval to be displayed on the screen.
        :param stdout: Sets the standard output
        :return: :class:`Progress` object
    """

    def __init__(self, interval=1, stdout=sys.stdout):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.total_length = 0
        self.interval = interval
        self.object_name = None

        self.last_printed_len = 0
        self.current_size = 0

        self.display_queue = Queue()
        self.initial_time = time.time()
        self.stdout = stdout
        self.start()

    def set_meta(self, total_length, object_name):
        """
        Metadata settings for the object. This method called before uploading
        object
        :param total_length: Total length of object.
        :param object_name: Object name to be showed.
        """
        self.total_length = total_length
        self.object_name = object_name
        self.prefix = self.object_name + ': ' if self.object_name else ''

    def run(self):
        displayed_time = 0
        while True:
            try:
                # display every interval secs
                task = self.display_queue.get(timeout=self.interval)
            except Empty:
                elapsed_time = time.time() - self.initial_time
                if elapsed_time > displayed_time:
                    displayed_time = elapsed_time
                self.print_status(current_size=self.current_size,
                                  total_length=self.total_length,
                                  displayed_time=displayed_time,
                                  prefix=self.prefix)
                continue

            current_size, total_length = task
            displayed_time = time.time() - self.initial_time
            self.print_status(current_size=current_size,
                              total_length=total_length,
                              displayed_time=displayed_time,
                              prefix=self.prefix)
            self.display_queue.task_done()
            if current_size == total_length:
                self.done_progress()

    def update(self, size):
        """
        Update object size to be showed. This method called while uploading
        :param size: Object size to be showed. The object size should be in
                     bytes.
        """
        if not isinstance(size, int):
            raise ValueError('{} type can not be displayed. '
                             'Please change it to Int.'.format(type(size)))

        self.current_size += size
        self.display_queue.put((self.current_size, self.total_length))

    def done_progress(self):
        self.total_length = 0
        self.object_name = None
        self.last_printed_len = 0
        self.current_size = 0

    def print_status(self, current_size, total_length, displayed_time, prefix):
        formatted_str = prefix + format_string(
            current_size, total_length, displayed_time)
        self.stdout.write(_REFRESH_CHAR + formatted_str + ' ' *
                          max(self.last_printed_len - len(formatted_str), 0))
        self.stdout.flush()
        self.last_printed_len = len(formatted_str)


def seconds_to_time(seconds):
    """
    Consistent time format to be displayed on the elapsed time in screen.
    :param seconds: seconds
    """
    minutes, seconds = divmod(int(seconds), 60)
    hours, m = divmod(minutes, 60)
    if hours:
        return _HOURS_OF_ELAPSED % (hours, m, seconds)
    else:
        return _MINUTES_OF_ELAPSED % (m, seconds)


def format_string(current_size, total_length, elapsed_time):
    """
    Consistent format to be displayed on the screen.
    :param current_size: Number of finished object size
    :param total_length: Total object size
    :param elapsed_time: number of seconds passed since start
    """

    n_to_mb = current_size / _KILOBYTE / _KILOBYTE
    elapsed_str = seconds_to_time(elapsed_time)

    rate = _RATE_FORMAT % (
        n_to_mb / elapsed_time) if elapsed_time else _UNKNOWN_SIZE
    frac = float(current_size) / total_length
    bar_length = int(frac * _BAR_SIZE)
    bar = (_FINISHED_BAR * bar_length +
           _REMAINING_BAR * (_BAR_SIZE - bar_length))
    percentage = _PERCENTAGE_FORMAT % (frac * 100)
    left_str = (
        seconds_to_time(
            elapsed_time / current_size * (total_length - current_size))
        if current_size else _UNKNOWN_SIZE)

    humanized_total = _HUMANINZED_FORMAT % (
        total_length / _KILOBYTE / _KILOBYTE) + _STR_MEGABYTE
    humanized_n = _HUMANINZED_FORMAT % n_to_mb + _STR_MEGABYTE

    return _DISPLAY_FORMAT % (bar, humanized_n, humanized_total, percentage,
                              elapsed_str, left_str, rate)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except S3Error as exc:
        print("error ouccured.", exc)
```